# Proof of $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k =E$ for measurable sets $E$ and $E_k$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let , $f_n:E\to [0,\infty]$ be a monotone increasing sequence of measurable functions converges pointwise to $f$ ; where $E$ is a measurable set. Choose a simple function $\phi:E\to [0,\infty)$ such that $\phi \le f$ on $E$ and choose a real number $a(0<a<1)$. Let , $E_k=\{x\in E:f_k(x) \ge a\phi(x)\}$ , for all $k\in \mathbb N$.

We have to prove , $\displaystyle \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k=E$.

It is a part of the proof a theorem and my book says it is clearly $\displaystyle \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k=E$. But I'm unable to understand it.

**My Work:**

From definition of $E_k$ it is clear that $E_k\subset E$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$. Then , $\displaystyle \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k\subset E$. Also it is clear to me that $E_1\subset E_2\subset E_3 \subset \cdots$ , as $f_k\le f_{k+1}$.  But how I prove the reverse inclusion ? Or any other way to show the equality.

Comment: Take an $x\in E$. If $f(x) = 0$, you're done (why?). Otherwise, $a\phi(x) < f(x)$. Now use $f_n(x) \to f(x)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer When $f_n\to f$ then $f_n\le f$. How I use it?

Comment: You want a $k$ with $f_k(x) \geqslant a\phi(x)$.

Comment: Yes. But how I show it ? We have $a\phi<f$ and $f_n \le f$.

Comment: It's more than just $f_n \leq f$, you have $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ as Daniel Fischer pointed. This means that you can find a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such as for every $n > N$, $a\phi(x) \leq f_n(x) \leq f(x)$.

Comment: @Hans As $f_n\to f$ so $\exists N$ such that $|f_n-f|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. Then , in particular , $f<f_N+\epsilon$. Then $a\phi<f<f_N+\epsilon$. As $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary so , $a\phi \le f_N$. Is it true?

Comment: @DanielFischer Is my last reason correct or not ? Please verify it and please response.

Comment: For $x \in E$ fixed, as already said, we want a $k$ with $f_k(x) \geq a\phi(x)$. Recall that $(f_n)_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, this means : $\forall \epsilon > 0 \quad \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \quad n>N \implies |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. As we have $a\phi < f$, we can pick $\epsilon >0$ such as $a\phi(x) \leq f(x) - \epsilon$. Then, for this $\epsilon$, we have a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with : $\forall n>N$, $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$, wich also means that we have $f(x) - \epsilon < f_n(x)$. So we found a special $k$ (take it as $k>N$) with $a\phi(x) \leq f_n(x)$.

Comment: By the way, I did not really check what you did. I actually said the same thing. So yes, it seems correct.